# SetWindowsHookEx, MouseClicks not firing callbacks on context menu / Menus

Tags: c#, winapi, setwindowshookex

I am writing an application to capture mouse clicks in Excel 2016 and above (this is not a keylogger) and capture the menu clicked in the Ribbon bar.

I used `SetWindowsHookEx()` to hook mouse capture (hooked to my application). The functionality works fine:

```
    using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
    {               
        var result =  SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
        GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }
```

But when I tried to click any menus (like the one attached below) from the Ribbon, the callback doesn't seem to be fired.

[image]

I searched Google and couldn't get any topic related to my issue.

I also tried with Spy++ and could see it captures `WM_LBUTTON[UP, DOWN]` only when the option "Windows of Same Thread" or "Windows of Same Process" check box is clicked under the Message option. I hope it doesn't use `SetWindowsHookEx()`?

[image]

Can anyone please direct me in the right direction?

Comment: This is what [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) are for.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable, I could trap the EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND event type using the SetWinEventHook() api function.  I had to set the hook on the excel process to listen. Anything you could share about why setwindowshookex failed? I still have used setwindowshookex for other mouse events.